# How can I make a second image move with the WASD keys after creating a literal object for it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn to move a second object with the WASD keys and I cannot find much specific information that details how it is done. I'm also having trouble resizing it. I'm currently exploring this game to learn all I can. 
https://jsfiddle.net/t2mjc5k1/ <=== code posted below.

I've tried a few prewritten javascript snippets that I saw online. I am using one that I found here on StackOverflow. I have also been using this website (https://keycode.info/) to better understand how event keycodes work.

```js
    // Arrow key codes
    var UP = 38,
        DOWN = 40,
        RIGHT = 39,
        LEFT = 37;
    //wasd keycodes

    /*var W = 87,
        A = 65, 
        S = 83,
        D = 68;*/

    // rocket object
    var rocket = {
     img: document.querySelector("#rocket"),
     x: 490,
     y: 390,
     width: 100
    };

    var UFO = {
     img: document.querySelector("#ufo"),
     x: 300,
     y: 200,
     width: 200  // Need to read up on x,y positioning.S
    };

    //sound array 
    var sounds = ["#Photon", "#Shrapnel"];

    var currentSound = null;

    const velocity = 8;

    let torpedo = document.querySelector("#torpedo"),
        startBtn = document.querySelector("#start"),
        fireBtn = document.querySelector("#fire"),
        ufo = document.querySelector("#ufo");


    // Initialize objects on the screen
    render ( );


    /*
    function startGameHandler( ) {
     "use strict"
        // Hide the intro screen, show the game screen
     introScreen.style.display = "none";
     gameScreen.style.display = "block";
     rocket.img.style.display = "block";
     ufo.style.display = "block";
    }
    */

    const startGameHandler = ( ) => { 
    "use strict"; 
    // Hide the intro screen, show the game screen 
    introScreen.style.display = "none"; 
    gameScreen.style.display = "block"; 
    rocket.img.style.display = "block"; 
    ufo.style.display = "block"; 
    }; 

    function fireTorpedoHandler( ) {
     "use strict"
        // Fire the photon torpedo!
     // CSS animation occurs whenever torpedo
     // 'left' property changes value
     torpedo.style.visibility = "visible";
     torpedo.style.left = (rocket.x - 200)+ "px";
    }
      


    const keydownHandler = event => {
        "use strict"
        if (event.keyCode == UP) {
            rocket.y -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == LEFT) {
            rocket.x -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === DOWN) {
            rocket.y += velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == RIGHT) {
            rocket.x += velocity;
        }

        render( );
    }


    //moving the UFO
    (function() {
      var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
      window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();


    function onKeyDown(event) {
      var keyCode = event.keyCode;
      switch (keyCode) {
        case 68: //d
          keyD = true;
          break;
        case 83: //s
          keyS = true;
          break;
        case 65: //a
          keyA = true;
          break;
        case 87: //w
          keyW = true;
          break;
      }
    }

    function onKeyUp(event) {
      var keyCode = event.keyCode;

      switch (keyCode) {
        case 68: //d
          keyD = false;
          break;
        case 83: //s
          keyS = false;
          break;
        case 65: //a
          keyA = false;
          break;
        case 87: //w
          keyW = false;
          break;
      }
    }

    //neccessary variables
    var clickX = 10;
    var clickY = 10;

    var keyW = false;
    var keyA = false;
    var keyS = false;
    var keyD = false;

    //main animation function
    function ufoBooster() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(ufoBooster);
      var canvas = document.getElementById("ufo");
      
      if (keyD == true) {
        clickX += 1;
      }
      if (keyS == true) {
        clickY += 1;
      }
      if (keyA == true) {
        clickX--;
      }
      if (keyW == true) {
        clickY--;
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(ufoBooster);

    // Moved here to get the arrow function to work.
    startBtn.addEventListener("click",startGameHandler,false);
    fireBtn.addEventListener("click",fireTorpedoHandler,false)
    window.addEventListener("keydown",keydownHandler,false);

    //ufo event listeners
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);



    function render( ) {
     "use strict"
        
     // position objects on the screen
     rocket.img.style.left = rocket.x + "px";
     rocket.img.style.top = rocket.y + "px";
        torpedo.style.left = (rocket.x +10) + "px";
     torpedo.style.top = (rocket.y+8) + "px";
     torpedo.style.visibility = "hidden";
        
        

    }
```

```css
    * { margin: 0; 
     padding: 0;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'spaceAge';
        src: url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.svg#space_ageregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    #introScreen {
     margin: 50px auto;
     padding: 50px 30px;
     width: 540px;
     height: 350px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #0d152a;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: white;
    }
    #title {
     font-size: 32px;
     line-height: 1.1em;
     font-family: spaceAge;
    }
    #introScreen img {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #introScreen h3 {
     clear: both;
     font-family: spaceAge;
     margin-top: 40px;
    }
    #introScreen div {
     margin-top: 40px;
     text-align: center;
    }

    button {
     font-family: spaceAge;
     font-size: 150%;
     padding: 4px 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: white;

     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;

     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
     background: linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);

     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
    button:hover {
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
     background: linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651); 
    }
    #gameScreen {
     margin: 50px auto;
     width: 600px;
     height: 450px;
     background-image: url("../images/bkg.jpg");
     display:none;
     position: relative;
    }
    #rocket {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
    }
    #torpedo {
     position: absolute;

     /* transition */
     -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
     -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
     transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    #ufo {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     
    }
    #gameUI {
     width: 560px;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     color: white;
     font-family: spaceAge;
     line-height: 1em;
    }
    #gameInfo {
     width: 450px;
     height: 120px;
     font-size: 120%;
     float: left;
    }
    #gameControls {
     width: 50px;
     height: 55px;
     padding-top: 5px;
     float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Space Arcade</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
     <section id="introScreen">
      <img src="images/introImage.jpg" alt="intro image">
      <span id="title">Big<br>Space<br>Sprite<br>Mover</span>
      <h3>How to play:</h3>
      <p>Use the arrow keys to move the rocket ship up, down, left, or right. Hit the <strong>Fire!</strong> button to fire a photon torpedo.</p>
      <div>
       <button id="start">Engage!</button>
      </div>
     </section>

     <section id="gameScreen">
      <div id="gameUI">
       <div id="gameInfo">
        <p>Dilithium fuel: 100%</p>
        <p>Phasers: 25</p>
        <p>Photon torpedoes: 10</p>
       </div>
       <div id="gameControls">
        <button type= button id="fire" >Fire!</button>
       </div>   
      </div>

      <!-- absolutely positioned elements -->
      <img id="ufo" src="images/ufo.png" alt="UFO">
      <img id="torpedo" src="images/torpedo.png" alt="torpedo">
      <img id="rocket" src="images/rocket.png" alt="Rocket Ship sprite">
     </section>
        
        
       <!--<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="photon.mp3" ></audio>-->


        
        <audio id="Photon">
          <source src="Photon.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
          <source src="Photon.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
        
        <audio id="Shrapnel">
          <source src="Shrapnel.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
          <source s`enter code here`rc="Shrapnel.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>

     <script src="js/program.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to learn to move the ufo image with the WASD keys. The rocket image is currently bound to the arrow keys.

Comment: You might want to check https://keyjs.dev, which includes some explanations of things like Alt Codes and virtual/mobile keyboards and will soon include information about cross-browser inconsistencies! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply duplicate the code that you have for the rocket and use it for the UFO. To bind the movement key to WASD instead, just extend the `if` statements in your `keydownHandler` function to include the WASD keys

```js
    // Arrow key codes
    var UP = 38,
        DOWN = 40,
        RIGHT = 39,
        LEFT = 37;
    //wasd keycodes

    var W = 87,
        A = 65, 
        S = 83,
        D = 68;

    // rocket object
    var rocket = {
     img: document.querySelector("#rocket"),
     x: 490,
     y: 390,
     width: 100
    };

    var UFO = {
     img: document.querySelector("#ufo"),
     x: 300,
     y: 200,
     width: 200  // Need to read up on x,y positioning.S
    };

    //sound array 
    var sounds = ["#Photon", "#Shrapnel"];

    var currentSound = null;

    const velocity = 8;

    let torpedo = document.querySelector("#torpedo"),
        startBtn = document.querySelector("#start"),
        fireBtn = document.querySelector("#fire"),
        ufo = document.querySelector("#ufo");


    // Initialize objects on the screen
    render ( );


    /*
    function startGameHandler( ) {
     "use strict"
        // Hide the intro screen, show the game screen
     introScreen.style.display = "none";
     gameScreen.style.display = "block";
     rocket.img.style.display = "block";
     ufo.style.display = "block";
    }
    */

    const startGameHandler = ( ) => { 
    "use strict"; 
    // Hide the intro screen, show the game screen 
    introScreen.style.display = "none"; 
    gameScreen.style.display = "block"; 
    rocket.img.style.display = "block"; 
    ufo.style.display = "block"; 
    }; 

    function fireTorpedoHandler( ) {
     "use strict"
        // Fire the photon torpedo!
     // CSS animation occurs whenever torpedo
     // 'left' property changes value
     torpedo.style.visibility = "visible";
     torpedo.style.left = (rocket.x - 200)+ "px";
    }
      


    const keydownHandler = event => {
        "use strict"
        if (event.keyCode == UP) {
            rocket.y -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == LEFT) {
            rocket.x -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === DOWN) {
            rocket.y += velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == RIGHT) {
            rocket.x += velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == W) {
            UFO.y -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == A) {
            UFO.x -= velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode === S) {
            UFO.y += velocity;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == D) {
            UFO.x += velocity;
        }

        render( );
    }


    //moving the UFO
    (function() {
      var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
      window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();

    //neccessary variables
    var clickX = 10;
    var clickY = 10;

    var keyW = false;
    var keyA = false;
    var keyS = false;
    var keyD = false;

    //main animation function
    function ufoBooster() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(ufoBooster);
      var canvas = document.getElementById("ufo");
      
      if (keyD == true) {
        clickX += 1;
      }
      if (keyS == true) {
        clickY += 1;
      }
      if (keyA == true) {
        clickX--;
      }
      if (keyW == true) {
        clickY--;
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(ufoBooster);

    // Moved here to get the arrow function to work.
    startBtn.addEventListener("click",startGameHandler,false);
    fireBtn.addEventListener("click",fireTorpedoHandler,false)
    window.addEventListener("keydown",keydownHandler,false);

    function render( ) {
     "use strict"
        
     // position objects on the screen
     rocket.img.style.left = rocket.x + "px";
     rocket.img.style.top = rocket.y + "px";
        UFO.img.style.left = UFO.x + "px";
     UFO.img.style.top = UFO.y + "px";
        torpedo.style.left = (rocket.x +10) + "px";
     torpedo.style.top = (rocket.y+8) + "px";
     torpedo.style.visibility = "hidden";
        
        

    }
```

```css
    * { margin: 0; 
     padding: 0;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'spaceAge';
        src: url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/space_age-webfont.svg#space_ageregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    #introScreen {
     margin: 50px auto;
     padding: 50px 30px;
     width: 540px;
     height: 350px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #0d152a;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: white;
    }
    #title {
     font-size: 32px;
     line-height: 1.1em;
     font-family: spaceAge;
    }
    #introScreen img {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #introScreen h3 {
     clear: both;
     font-family: spaceAge;
     margin-top: 40px;
    }
    #introScreen div {
     margin-top: 40px;
     text-align: center;
    }

    button {
     font-family: spaceAge;
     font-size: 150%;
     padding: 4px 8px;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: white;

     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;

     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);
     background: linear-gradient(top, #a3a3a3, #000);

     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
     box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    }
    button:hover {
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651);
     background: linear-gradient(top, #acc7a3, #506651); 
    }
    #gameScreen {
     margin: 50px auto;
     width: 600px;
     height: 450px;
     background-image: url("../images/bkg.jpg");
     display:none;
     position: relative;
    }
    #rocket {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
    }
    #torpedo {
     position: absolute;

     /* transition */
     -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
     -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
     transition: left 0.5s ease-out 0s;
    }
    #ufo {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     
    }
    #gameUI {
     width: 560px;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     color: white;
     font-family: spaceAge;
     line-height: 1em;
    }
    #gameInfo {
     width: 450px;
     height: 120px;
     font-size: 120%;
     float: left;
    }
    #gameControls {
     width: 50px;
     height: 55px;
     padding-top: 5px;
     float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Space Arcade</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
     <section id="introScreen">
      <img src="images/introImage.jpg" alt="intro image">
      <span id="title">Big<br>Space<br>Sprite<br>Mover</span>
      <h3>How to play:</h3>
      <p>Use the arrow keys to move the rocket ship up, down, left, or right. Hit the <strong>Fire!</strong> button to fire a photon torpedo.</p>
      <div>
       <button id="start">Engage!</button>
      </div>
     </section>

     <section id="gameScreen">
      <div id="gameUI">
       <div id="gameInfo">
        <p>Dilithium fuel: 100%</p>
        <p>Phasers: 25</p>
        <p>Photon torpedoes: 10</p>
       </div>
       <div id="gameControls">
        <button type= button id="fire" >Fire!</button>
       </div>   
      </div>

      <!-- absolutely positioned elements -->
      <img id="ufo" src="images/ufo.png" alt="UFO">
      <img id="torpedo" src="images/torpedo.png" alt="torpedo">
      <img id="rocket" src="images/rocket.png" alt="Rocket Ship sprite">
     </section>
        
        
       <!--<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="photon.mp3" ></audio>-->


        
        <audio id="Photon">
          <source src="Photon.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
          <source src="Photon.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>
        
        <audio id="Shrapnel">
          <source src="Shrapnel.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
          <source s`enter code here`rc="Shrapnel.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        </audio>

     <script src="js/program.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought that it took much more than that after visiting this website. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2012/09/11/back-to-basics-using-keyboard-events-in-javascript/

Comment: If you manage to move an image using some codes, you should be able to move another image using the same code. So, you should check how is it moved differently, and modify the related code accordingly. You already have a working code, just ensure you understand how it works

Comment: Just curious. What keeps the two images from moving at the same time? I'm just trying to understand how the code works.

Comment: The two images move separately because of the different keys that modifies each of its `x` and `y` values. Take a look at your `keydownHandler` function

Answer (score 2):

Hello fellow game developer (so it seems), why are you not using canvas or other libraries like PixiJS?

Anyway, how I like to do it, is to actually create separate objects for the controls and the checks for whether the key is down:

**Objects/Variables**

```
//Controls
var controls = {
    "ufo":
    {
        "left":[65, 74], //A/J
        "right":[68, 76], //D/L
        "up":[87, 73], //W/I
        "down":[83, 75] //S/K
    }

    "rocket":{
        "left":[37], //LEFT
        "right":[39], //RIGHT
        "up":[38], //UP
        "down":[40] //DOWN
    },

    "pause":[80], //P
    "mute":[77] //M
};

//Is Key down?
//For eg, if the W (87) key is down, isKeyDown[87] will be true, otherwise, false.    
var isKeyDown = {}; 

//To Set: 
for(var i in controls)
    if(controls.hasOwnProperty(i))
        if(i=="rocket" || i=="ufo"){ //special cases where we have nested objects
            for(var j in controls[i]){
                for(var k=0;j<controls[i][j].length;k++)
                    isKeyDown[controls[i][j][k]] = false;   
            }
        }
        else for(var j=0;j<controls[i].length;j++)
            isKeyDown[controls[i][j]] = false;
```

This is **very good for scalability**: You can include button presses for other things like pause and mute. You can also have multiple keypresses to do the same thing (eg. I added WASD and IJKL for you so *BOTH* can now move the UFO).

**Event Listeners**

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    for(i in isKeyDown)
        if(isKeyDown.hasOwnProperty(i) && e.keyCode == i)
            isKeyDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    if(isKeyDown[e.keyCode] != undefined)
        isKeyDown[e.keyCode] = false;
    else return;

    //Actual movements can be handled elsewhere in your tick/main animation function (see below)

    //Pausing and muting (just in case you want them):
    for(var j=0;j<controls["pause"].length;j++)
        if(e.keyCode==controls["pause"][j]){
            //PAUSE GAME
            break;
        }

    for(var j=0;j<controls["mute"].length;j++)
        if(e.keyCode==controls["mute"][j]){
            //MUTE GAME
            break;
        }
}, false);
```

**Inside your tick/Animation Function**
    //FOR MOVEMENTS. To go in your main tick/animation function

```
var movements = {
    "ufo":{
        "up":false,
        "down":false,
        "right":false,
        "left":false
    },
    "rocket":{
        "up":false,
        "down":false,
        "right":false,
        "left":false
    }
};

//Rocket
for(var i in controls["rocket"])
    if(controls.hasOwnProperty(i))
    for(var j=0;j<controls["rocket"][i].length;j++){
        if(isKeyDown[controls["rocket"][i][j]])
            movements["rocket"][i] = true;
    }

//UFO
for(var i in controls["ufo"])
    if(controls.hasOwnProperty(i))
    for(var j=0;j<controls["ufo"][i].length;j++){
        if(isKeyDown[controls["ufo"][i][j]])
            movements["ufo"][i] = true;
    }
```

**For the Actual movements**

```
//Actual movements, also to go into your tick function or equivalent handler:

//Rocket
if (event.keyCode == movements["rocket"]["up"]) {
    rocket.y -= velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode == movements["rocket"]["left"]) {
    rocket.x -= velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode === movements["rocket"]["down"]) {
    rocket.y += velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode == movements["rocket"]["right"]) {
    rocket.x += velocity;
}

//UFO
if (event.keyCode == movements["ufo"]["up"]) {
    UFO.y -= velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode == movements["ufo"]["left"]) {
    UFO.x -= velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode === movements["ufo"]["down"]) {
    UFO.y += velocity;
}
if (event.keyCode == movements["ufo"]["right"]) {
    UFO.x += velocity;
}
```

While the previous user has already "answered" your question, I believe that as you scale up your game to become larger with more functions, this method will be more useful.